# threading.timer printing only last value of for loop

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, for-loop, python-multithreading

Hey I am stuck in a situation where I have if condition inside for loop. I wanted to get output with 10 seconds delay if condition satisfies. Instead of desired output I get all values at same time and then last value repeats with 10 second delay. Below is code

```
import threading
import time
a=[2, 3, 4, 10, 12]
b=2
for x in a:
    if x >2:
        def delayfunction():
            print(x,"is not ok")
        threading.Timer(10, delayfunction).start()
        delayfunction()
    else:
        print(x," is less than equal to 2")
```

output is:

```
2  is less than equal to 2
3 is not ok
4 is not ok
10 is not ok
12 is not ok
12 is not ok
12 is not ok
12 is not ok
12 is not ok
```

I will be very much grateful if could get some assist here. Thanks

Comment: `threading.Timer` seems a bit over-kill-ish here. Why not just `time.sleep(10)`?

Comment: @twalberg because sleep will hold the whole script, what I wanted to achieve was script to goes on but run certain attributes after particular time. Thankfully I get my answer below.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, then. Wasn't really stated in the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your scope. After the timer, the delayfunction will print the current x value, not the value of x at the start of the timer.

You need to pass the x as argument like this:

```
import threading
import time
a=[2, 3, 4, 10, 12]
b=2
for x in a:
    if x >2:
        def delayfunction(current_x):
            print(current_x,"is not ok")
        threading.Timer(10, delayfunction, [x]).start()
        delayfunction(x)
    else:
        print(x," is less than equal to 2")
```

The output will be:

```
2  is less than equal to 2
3 is not ok
4 is not ok
10 is not ok
12 is not ok
3 is not ok
4 is not ok
10 is not ok
12 is not ok
```

If you don't want the output before the timer, just don't call your delayfunction in your if statement.

In fact, threading.Timer will call your function (given as second parameter) after the 10 seconde (given as first parameter)

```
import threading
import time
a=[2, 3, 4, 10, 12]
b=2
for x in a:
    if x >2:
        def delayfunction(current_x):
            print(current_x,"is not ok")
        threading.Timer(10, delayfunction, [x]).start()
    else:
        print(x," is less than equal to 2")
```

will output:

```
2  is less than equal to 2 # immediatly
3 is not ok                # before 10 second
4 is not ok                # before 10 second
10 is not ok               # before 10 second
12 is not ok               # before 10 second
```

Comment: much appreciated thats exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much

Comment: @AhsanNaseem: Welcome to StackOverflow. If someone's answer solves your question, then mark this answer as "accepted" (use the green checkmark under the voting widget). It gives credit to the answer's author, and lets the community know this question is solved.